# Includes in Rails: How to mix OR and outer joins in the same query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to use rails' ActiveRecord interface to get records, but it's proving a bit difficult. Here is the issue:

3 tables: things, users, collaborations

3 joining tables: things_users, collaborations_things, collaboration_users

I'm trying to get things (in pseudo SQL, skipping the JOINS)

```
things WHERE
things.criteria = something OR
user_id IN things_users.user_id OR
user_id IN users_collaboration.user_id
```

Of note, things might not have users, or collaborations, so outer joins are needed.

The models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  // Unrelated stuff
  has_and_belongs_to_many :collaborations
end

class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
    // Unrelated
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    has_and_belongs_to_many :collaborations
end

class Collaboration < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :members, :join_table => 'collaborations_users', :association_foreign_key => 'user_id'
end
```

I've tried using the straight up interface, arel and direct SQL, but for some reason I can't find the correct magic to make it all work.

If someone could help that'd be great.
Thanks

Comment: Rails does not support `OR` in ActiveRecord, to do it you have to go a layer deeper into https://github.com/rails/arel - most people just use SQL strings when they need to deal with `OR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL for that could look like (substituting appropriately for <> sections):

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM things t
LEFT OUTER JOIN things_users tu ON t.id = tu.thing_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN collaborations_things ct ON t.id = ct.thing_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN collaborations_users cu ON ct.collaboration_id = cu.collaboration_id
WHERE <things table criteria> OR tu.user_id = <user_id> OR cu.user_id = <user_id>
```

To get that with ActiveRecord you could use:

```
Thing.joins("LEFT JOIN things_users ON things.id = things_users.thing_id LEFT JOIN collaborations_things ON thing.id = collaborations_things.thing_id LEFT JOIN collaborations_users ON collaborations_things.collaboration_id = collaborations_users.collaboration_id").where(["<other criteria> OR things_users.user_id = :user_id OR collaborations_users = :user_id", {user_id: @user_id}]
```

Comment: After replacing thing with the actual name, it worked. Thanks a lot :)